# validación con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy iniciandome con ajax y php y tengo dificultad para resolver una validación, debo de enviar como mínimo el valor escrito en alguno de 4 inputs mediante XMLHttpRequest donde se ha de comprobar que el valor ingresado sea un numero de un solo dígito (un numero menor a 10) , si no es validado debo retornar cual es el input donde esta el error. La duda es: Como retorno al cliente el input incorrecto?

```
HTML

<div id='midiv'>
<input type="text" id="id1"/>
<input type="text" id="id2"/>
<input type="text" id="id3"/>
<input type="text" id="id4"/>
<input onclick="guardaCombinacion()" type="button" value="GUARDAR COMBINACION">
</div>

JS

function guardaCombinacion(){

var input1 = document.getElementById("id1").value;
var input2 = document.getElementById("id2").value;
var input3 = document.getElementById("id3").value;
var input4 = document.getElementById("id4").value;

let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
peticion.open("GET","index3.php?n1="+input1+"&n2="+input2+"&n3="+input3+"&n4="+input4,true);
peticion.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
peticion.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(peticion.readyState==4){   

         if(peticion.status==200){
        
            let textoRespuesta = peticion.responseText;                
            let objetoJSON=JSON.parse(textoRespuesta);                
            let respuesta = objetoJSON.respuesta;                
            document.getElementById("midiv").innerHTML=respuesta;
        }        
    }    
   peticion.send();
```

}

PHP  // CONTROLAR UN SOLO DIGITO
<?php

```
$nro1 = $_GET['n1']; // valor: 1
$nro2 = $_GET['n2']; //valor:  5
$nro3 = $_GET['n3']; // valor: 11  //DEBERIA MOSTRAR MENSAJE INPUT INCORRECTO
$nro4 = $_GET['n4']; // VALOR: 6
$correcto = "NUMERO DE 0 A 10";
&incorrecto = "NUMERO FUERA DE RANGO";

  if ($nro1 < 10 && $nro2 < 10 & $nro3 < 10 && $nro4 < 10) {

  echo '{"respuesta":"'.$correcto.'"}';
```

}else{

```
  echo '{"resp33":"'.$incorrecto.'"}';
}
?>
```

Comment: Para retornar al cliente al input correcto podrias hacer un focus al input que es correo por el ID del elemento 
> document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();

Comment: lo que el cliente debe mostrar es el input incorrecto con un mensaje, por ej "El input 3 es incorrecto". Esta bien lo que dices pero tengo que hacerlo mediante json y por mensaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, es mejor que si quieres que el usuario pueda poner letras y solamente pueta poner caracteres númericos, el tipo del input sea number en vez de text.

Lo más sencillo es que hagas una comprobación mediante javascript de si el valor del input es mayor a 10, en caso de serlo, puedes asignarle a ese input una clase css, la cual cambie la apariencia del input para que sea más visible y si tambien lo deseas puedes lanzar una alerta indicando donde está el problema.

Algo así:

HTML:

```
<div id='midiv'>
    <input type="number" id="id1" />
    <input type="number" id="id2" />
    <input type="number" id="id3" />
    <input type="number" id="id4" />
    <input onclick="guardaCombinacion()" type="button" value="GUARDAR COMBINACION">
</div>
```

Javascript ( pongo solo el input id1 como ejemplo, con los demás es lo mismo )

```
<script>

    function guardaCombinacion() {

        if (document.getElementById("id1").value > 10){
            document.getElementById("id1").classList.add("invalido");
            alert("El valor de id1 no puede ser mayor a 10");
        } else{
            document.getElementById("id1").classList.remove("invalido");
        }
    }
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
 .invalido{
     border-color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo, si el valor del input es mayor a 10, le asignamos la clase "invalido" al input para que el borde del mismo cambie a rojo. Si no se cumple la condición de que sea mayor a 10, le quitamos la clase para que no aparezca marcado como erroneo.

Hay que mencionar, que esto es una comprobación antes de enviar el formulario y a nivel de cliente. Por mucho que esta validación sea correcta, siempre es recomendable realizar las comprobaciones necesarias en el servidor, antes de guardar los datos en la base de datos.

En el caso de hacer la comprobación una vez mandado el formulario, lo que puedes hacer es practicamente lo que estabas haciendo, pero en vez de hacer todas las comproabciones en un if, hacerlas por separado para así saber cual es el que está mal.

```
$respuesta = "";

 if ($nro1 > 10){
    $respuesta .= "El número 1 es mayor de 10. ";
}
if ($nro2 > 10){
    $respuesta .= "El número 2 es mayor de 10. ";
}
if ($nro3 > 10){
    $respuesta .= "El número 3 es mayor de 10. ";
}
if ($nro4 > 10){
    $respuesta .= "El número 4 es mayor de 10 ";
}

if($respuesta == ""){
$respuesta .= "Todos los números están bien";
}

echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Como puedes ver, vamos comprobando si los valores son correctos y de no serlos vamos añadiendo a la variable $respuesta, la indicación.
Si al final esta cadena sigue estando vacia, significa que los 4 números son correctos. Si no está vacia, lo que contendrá será la indicación de cada uno de los números que está mal.

Al final mediante la funcion json_encode convertimos la variable a json y la imprimimos con un echo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ibai, muy clara tu respuesta.